# Populate inconsitent-structured data into DataTable

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I've this text :

```
"2221100002","0"
"2221100002","0", "ExtraCol1"
"2221100002","0", "ExtraCol1", "ExtraCol2"
```

Now I want to populate this content into a data table **or a 2D Array** using VB.NET, it'll be easy if every lines share the same columns number, in this case is the "," delimiter. I'm having trouble to achieve something like this :

```
Col1       Col2      Col3            Col4 
2221100002  0      
2221100002  0      
2221100002  0      ExtraCol1       
2221100002  0      ExtraCol1       ExtraCol2
```

Is this possible? And the most important thing is if the solution will produce good performance!

Comment: To use the "," you need to include it for all of the columns, including those that are blank.

Answer (score 0):

You can just split your input and then stop filling each row when you have inserted all your values.
Something like this might work :

```
Dim input As String() 'get it filled from your source
Dim array As String(,)
ReDim array(10, 5)
For i As Integer = 0 To 10
    Dim split As String() = input(i).Split(",")
    For j As Integer = 0 To 10
        array(i, j) = split(j)
        If (j >= split.Length - 1) Then
            j = Integer.MaxValue
        End If
    Next

Next
```

Answer (score 0):

If you first store everything in a list and convert to an array at the end you don't need to worry about array dimensions. Let .NET figure that out for you.

I'm assuming the text is in an external file for this. A DataTable can be filled the same way, I used a 2D-array as the result type here.

```
Private Function GetData(ByVal path As String) As String()()
    Dim results As New List(Of String())

    Dim lines As String() = File.ReadAllLines(path)
    lines.ToList.ForEach(Sub(x) results.Add(x.Split(","c)))

    Return results.ToArray
End Function
```